# Rotation of Fluid in a Cylinder

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

Question: [image]

See what I tried below and verify if I'm wrong. I need help here.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just need to get the height of the paraboloid (air) in the cylinder. Knowing that the volume of the paraboloid is half of the cylinder of the same height,

$$H_{paraboloid}=2*H_{cylinder}$$

where $H_{cylinder}$ is the height of air when it is not rotating, $0.2\ m$, therefore $$H_{paraboloid}=0.4m=y$$

substituting the value in the equation,

$$y=\frac{\omega^2x^2}{2g}$$

where $x=0.1\ m$, (radius of paraboloid) and $g=9.81\ m/s^2$, you will get

$$\omega=28.014\ rad/s = 267.51 rev/min$$